# Why not "DOT lol" domains?

Tags: domains

How would one go about creating a website using the ".lol" domain? Is it even possible? And if not, why not?

Comment: Do you have a spare $100,000 lying around?

Comment: I actually do. How would I use the $100,000 to do that?

Comment: high risk for getting ROI yet somewhat awesome and a number of possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

As of the this year, it is possible for you to take control of your own top-level domain, through a new ICANN process. You can read about the ICANN guidelines for becoming a sponsor of a top level domain here:

http://www.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtlds/draft-rfp-24oct08-en.pdf

It requires ~$185,000 in application fees. Sort of the definition of a high barrier to entry.

This [organization](http://www.centralregistrysolutions.com/) claims that they'll help you through the process. More info from [Wired](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/03/canon-domain/). [This blog](http://timg.ws/2008/07/31/how-to-run-your-own-top-level-domain/) explains the technical aspects of the implementation.

Comment: Wow - this seems like a stupid idea.  I'm also very surprised I haven't heard of it before.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: Also you can't just go creating any TLD. ".lol" might be OK since it's a common phrase but you won't be able to create ".coke" or ".mcdonalds".

Comment: Humorous postscript: Google has applied for the .lol TLD http://mashable.com/2012/05/31/google-domain/